# how to make a regular expressions to accept only digits not started with zero or zero only?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis, digit

I'm trying to create a regex to accept digits not starting with zero or a single zero digit.

Example matches

```
0
50
798
```

Example rejects

```
01
046
0014
00
0001
```

My attempt was to use `/[0]|[1-9][0-9]*/` to match the values in the following text:

> 0, 50, 798
>   01, 046, 0014, 00, 0001

This attempt can be run at http://regexr.com/3bb00

Comment: You should include the regular expression language and your test case in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following regex :

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)$
```

see Demo https://regex101.com/r/zT8uI2/2

This regex contains 2 part, `0` or `[1-9]\d*` which is a digit that doesn't starts with zero.

Note that if you want to match your numbers within other texts you need a word boundary instead of start and end anchors :

```
\b(0|[1-9]\d*)\b
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r/zT8uI2/3

Comment: `(?:\d+)?` can be written as `\d*`

Comment: This doesn't match comma separated values like the OP showed.

Comment: @Anonymous there is no comma separated in OP's expected result!

Comment: @zuhair There wasn't need to use that! it was none capture group token! comes with `?` (like `:?`)

Comment: @Kasra Look at [the example](http://regexr.com/3bb00). The values are separated by commas. The values in the question were just edited in by a user.

Comment: @Anonymous if the information isn't in the question, it doesn't exist. If the OP has constraints, they need to provide that detail. For the asked question, this answer is correct.

Comment: @Anonymous Now I see that, although it wasn't mentioned on question! I added some explains about that!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have two cases in your regex:

1. Match a single zero
2. Match digits that don't start with zero.

The first case is easy: `/0/`

The second case is also pretty easy `/[1-9]\d*/`. The `[1-9]` matches the digit that is not 0. Then, we can have 0 or more digits.

To get both of these cases, just use a bar to do either or

```
/0|[1-9]\d*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, why not something like..

```
if(input[0] == '0' && input.size() > 1) // reject
else //accept
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this http://regexr.com/3bb09

Took the tip from https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s06.html
and improved it to negate numbers starting with 0.

RE: `\b[^0,]*([1-9][0-9]*|0)\b`
Text: 0, 50, 798, 01, 046, 0014, 00, 0001
Matched only 0, 50 and 798

Thanks
Venkat